# Comment insérer une balise html <a> dans le titre de la colonne d'un GridView en asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working for the first time in asp.net/webforms for my internship. I have to display a GridView fill with information coming from class. I already create my GridView dynamically with BoundField. However I want the HeaderText of each column to be a link toward the configuration page of the object represented by the column. But I can't find how to insert this link dynamically... Maybe I should try with Javascript, but how ?

The GridView code in .aspx :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Objet" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The GridView code in .cs :

```
foreach (Objet objet in m_objets)
{
    dataColumn = new DataColumn(objet.getNom(), typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

    boundField = new BoundField();
    boundField.HeaderText = string.Format("<a href='/dc6_consignes_decapage.aspx'>" + objet.getNom() + "</a>");
    boundField.DataField = objet.getNom();
    GridView_Consigne.Columns.Add(boundField);
}
```

[Here the actual GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFIpP.png)

Thank's for your help !

Comment: Please write your question in English, since [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Header in the GridView like this and add a Control to the Cell.

```
HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
hl.NavigateUrl = "/Page2.aspx";
hl.Text = "Link to Page 2";

GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Controls.Add(hl);
```

This needs to be done on every page load, and that includes a PostBack since they are dynamically added Controls.